# What is the significance of -- in kernel parameters?

Tags: boot, kernel

I've been customising some kernel parameters and notice that on some guides it has something like

`initrd=/blahblah.gz -- quiet`

and others only have

`initrd=/blahblah.gz quiet`

I've tried both and noticed no difference - is there one? if so, what does the double dash do?

Comment: In commands, `--` is often used to stop the command from processing "flags" and only process "parameters" (like filenames) after that.  In Grub or other bootloaders, I'm not sure what the significance is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to pass a file as the parameter to the kernel. The filename of a file contains a dash at the first character of the filename (i.e. `-Justin`). If you'd write:

```
kernel-2.3.4 -Justin --
```

then `-Justin` would be treated as a kernel _parameter_ (or maybe I should say, 'a flag', as killermist wrote it). Thank God, such parameter (such flag) does not exist.

If on the other hand, you'd write:

```
kernel-2.3.4 -- -Justin
```

then '-Justin` would be treated as an actual _file[name]_.

```
kernel-2.3.4 -param1 -param2 -param3 -- file1 file2 -Justin
```

If you invoke a program from the command line, `--` is used to inform a program, that _after_ `--` there will only be filenames / some other objects (objects different than the 'native' switches for the program - by native switches i mean i.e. -a -b -c -s etc.).